# Broadcast receiver working on emulator but not on working real device (Android Oreo)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, background-service

Broadcast receiver it's work perfectly when I kill my application it work in background. but i 
    installed my real device it's don't when i kill application.

```
> Java Code

    public class BackgroundService extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Send Message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

> MainActivity
     BackgroundService backgroundService;
      @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(backgroundService,intentFilter);
    }


> Manifests 



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>

    <receiver android:name=".BackgroundService">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts

Answer (score 1):

**From android 8 onwards, if you have any implicit broadcast, you have to register it within your activity not in manifest**
In your case

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/> <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
```

seems to be implicit broadcast. Try registering them in your activity class using **intentFilter.addAction(Your Action)**

Also unregister you receiver in **onStop**  by 
calling **unregisterReceiver(Receiver instance)**