# Android 8.1 : broadcast receive does not work when I restart the smartphone

Tags: java, android

I am designing an android application in java and I would like it to launch when the smartphone starts up I of course registered a BroadcastReceiver for the BOOT event of my phone as explained here but it does not work on Android 10 if not for info it worked on Android 4.1.

Can you help me please ?

Here is my code:

Manifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.openclassrooms.fr.premierprojet">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".PremiereActivite">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".StartAppOnBoot">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Classe Main :

```
    package com.openclassrooms.fr.premierprojet;
 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
 
 
public class PremiereActivite extends Activity {
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Classe Diffuseur :

```
    package com.openclassrooms.fr.premierprojet;
 
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
public class StartAppOnBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, PremiereActivite.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Cordially.

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60705108/broadcast-receiver-working-on-emulator-but-not-on-working-real-device-android-o/60705465#60705465

Comment: I read on the internet that the broadcast receive is no longer functional from the API 26 to start a service when starting the phone and that we must now use a notification channel!

Can you show me how to do it please?

Comment: help me please.